# How to write console output to a text file in cpp?

Tags: c++, cmd

I'm trying to write console data into a separate text file in cpp. Anybody help me with sample code.

Comment: console data of what process? your own process? some other process you create?

Comment: What is "console data"? How does your current approach look like?

Comment: Anybody who search for an answer look for user11977's answer. It is the correct one.

Answer (score 20):

There are various ways to do this. You could redirect it from the command line with `programname > out.txt`. Or you could use `freopen("out.txt","w",stdout);` at the start of your program.

Comment: This was working well for me. But suddenly the cmd console outputs were completely invisible. When I remove this line, cmd outputs were visible back

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write from your own process, I'd suggest a simple print method

```
void print(const string str, ostream & output)
{
    output << str;
}
```

Then you can call

```
print("Print this", cout);
```

for console output, or

```
ofstream filestream("filename.out");
print("Print this", filestream);
```

to write into a file "filename.out". Of course you gain most, if `print` is a class method that outputs all the object's specific information you need and this way you can direct the output easily to different streams.

Comment: The `print` function you defined has almost no benefit.  You can just as easily write `cout << "Print this";` for you first example and `filestream << "Print this";" in the second example.  Unless `print` add some extra logic (perhaps writing a timestamp or perhaps writing to standard output and a file), there is no benefit to such a function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a child process and redirect its output you could do something like this:

```
FILE* filePtr = popen("mycmd");
FILE* outputPtr = fopen("myfile.txt");

if(filePtr && outputPtr) {
    char tmp;
    while((tmp = getc(filePtr)) != EOF)
        putc(tmp, outputPtr);

    pclose(filePtr);
    fclose(outputPtr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

bbtrb wrote:

> void print(const string str, ostream &
>   output) {
>       output << str; }

Better than this is of course

```
ostream& output(ostream& out, string str) {out << str; return out;}
```

so that you can even have the manipulated output stream returned by the function.

Answer (score 0):

smerrimans answer should help you out.

There is also the option to implement your own streambuf and use it with std::cout and std::cerr to store printouts to file instead of printing to console. I did that a while ago to redirect printouts to some sort of rotating logs with timestamps.

You will need to read up a little bit on how it works and [this book](http://www.angelikalanger.com/iostreams.html) helped me get it right.

If that's not what you're after it is a bit of overkill though.

Answer (score 0):

Create file -> redirect input into file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string file_name;
    std::string str;
  
    std::cout << "Add file name:";
    std::cin >> file_name;

    std::cout << "Open file:" << file_name << std::endl;

    std::ofstream oFile(file_name);

    if (!oFile) {
        std::cout << "ERROR: we can't open file:" << file_name << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "File is open: " << oFile.is_open() << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Enter you sentence into file:\n";
    getline(std::cin >> std::ws, str);
    oFile << str;
    oFile.close();


    return 0;
}
```