# Visual Studio 2022 - How to save console output in .txt file and still see it in the console (i.e without redirection)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, file-io, console

hopefully nothing too complicated :)
When I debug my application in VS 2022, I would like all the `std::cout` that is in the console to be saved to a .txt file, but also still show in the console itself. I added `> output.txt` to the command line arguments, but realized that means nothing will show in the console :/

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)

Comment: Still struggling to figure out how to add tee...some other post says that command line arguments in visual studio do not support the pipe operator..

Comment: Yes, command line arguments are supplied to your executable, they are not interpreted by some command interpreter. However you can use tee-like stream in your code.

Comment: Does the thread answers your question? [How to save a C++ console output in a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22904029/how-to-save-a-c-console-output-in-a-text-file)

Answer (score 0):

i think u can u swich case in a do-while loop

1 is input, which u can choose to save in text file

2 is output, which read your text file

Or you can just do like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string s;
    cout << "Enter something: ";
    getline(cin, s);
    fstream file;
    file.open("text.txt", ios::out);
    file << s;
    file.close();
    file.open("text.txt", ios::in);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        string line;
        while (getline(file, line))
        {
            cout << line << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use OutputDebugStringA and cout at the same time.

And set `Redirect all Output Window text to the Immediate Window` in Tool> Option.